# What happens to Omar Sy's character "Barry"?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, jurassic-world

Of all of the loose ends left by Jurassic World, the biggest question I am left with is what happens to Barry?  One of the raptors is trying to get him while he takes cover in a log, and Chris Pratt's Owen catches the raptor's attention, and leads them away.  To my recollection, Barry is not seen again during the movie.

Comment: @jmassey60 If I remeber correctly, we see him again at the end of the film helping out injured people with Owen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I watched the film again last night, and you do in fact see Barry one more time, in the Costa Rican first aid camp, for just a little less than 2 seconds, and he said something to someone off screen.  I could not make out what he said, was about 2 words or so.  I guess maybe we might see something in a sequel or an interview or something, but my guess is that it will just be assumed that he

1. somehow knew he was safe from the other three raptors (not having seen one hit with a rocket) and the Indominus Rex,
2. jogged the substantial distance back to the raptor paddock through the unfamiliar woods in total darkness,
3. found an operational vehicle and drove to the main compound,
4. and flew out on the last available evacuation vehicle, the helicopter that Lowery called in.

[image]

I am dissatisfied with this, but that's the fault of the movie, and I doubt it'll ever be covered in any more detail.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, these are always the scenes that get the snip during the edited process.

I can think one example off the top of my head: In Watchmen, there is quite a significant character 'Hollis Mason' who plays the original 'Nite Owl'. In the cinema version, he is never heard from again after a scene with Daniel (new Nite Owl). However, in the directors cut, there is quite a chunky and gruesome death scene that was cut out of the final film. Why? Time restraints maybe?

I think the answer to your question is: The scene was shot but likely to have been cut out, as although Barry had quite a bit of screen time, he isn't a significant character. (Much like Hollis Mason)

Comment: That does answer the question of "why did we not see his rescue/escape/death", but I was pretty sure that was the case.  What I don't know, and can't find any real answer on, is "what happened".  I disagree with the analogy of Watchmen's Hollis Mason, because his death adds nothing to the story other than being faithful to Moore's comic.  After all, he would have died 12 hours later in the explosion even if he hadn't been bludgeoned to death, and Dan would have made no different decisions about stopping Adrian.  Barry's fate has impact on the inevitable sequel and remains the only name lost.

Comment: @jmassey360 Well, maybe it's elaborated in some possible Director's Whatever Extended Cut.